# Syntax for including node.js modules in .js files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, include, npm, phantomjs

Using npm, I grabbed this package. https://npmjs.org/package/phantom-crawl

How do I run it? - The [example script](https://raw.github.com/vmeurisse/phantomCrawl/master/example.js) gave me this error:

> Error: Cannot find module './src/PhantomCrawl'

```
phantomjs://bootstrap.js:289
phantomjs://bootstrap.js:254 in require
example.js:3
```

Specifically this line needs to be changed; but unsure of the nodejs path syntax to use for this:

```
var PhantomCrawl = require('./src/PhantomCrawl');
```

Comment: Strange, it worked for me. What Node version are you using? I'm on 0.10.13.

Comment: I am also on 0.10.13. I'm sure that `git clone`ing it would work; however am trying to figure out how to do it out of just the `npm install phantom-crawl`...

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it relative to the `src` directory.
So if you installed locally using `npm install phantom-crawl` you would need to `cd node_modules/phantom-crawl` before you can run the example. Which also happens to be in that directory.

Comment: Wait, so `npm install` is no more useful than `git clone`? - So I should just setup an environmental variable to `node_modules` and work from there? :/

Comment: Well no.. npm installs dependencies and such. But that example specifically requires the file in the src directory. From you project you should be able to use require("phantom-crawl")